# Where to put template level style in ember project

Tags: ember.js

In my ember js project I have a style sheet where it should only available inside the given template how do I achieve that properly? I mean where to put that style sheet?

And how do I reference it to my template?

Comment: Is the template style scope you are referring to part of a component?  Or a route or application level template?

Answer (score 1):

Create css file under `styles/style1.css` and include that file in `styles/app.css` like `@import 'style1.css';`.
If you would like to specify component specific css stylesheets then you can try [ember-component-css](https://github.com/ebryn/ember-component-css) addon.